# Replacing Spring Cloud Server Placeholder in a plain text file

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-config

I have a plain text file in the Config Git Repository along with other config files.

```
.
└── app-a-config/
    ├── application.yml
    ├── application-local.yml
    └── another-config.xml
```

Contents of `application.yml`

```yaml
someconfig:
  value: 100
```

Contents of `application-local.yml`

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
   url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/localdb
   username: appuser
   password: localpassword
```

Contents of `another-config.xml`

```xml
<name>${profile}-another-conf</name>
<connection>
    <url>${spring.datasource.url}</url>
    <username>${spring.datasource.username}</username>
    <password>${spring.datasource.password}</password>
</connection>
<someconf>${someconfig.value}</someconf>
```

Whenever I call the `{configserveruri}/app-a/local/master/another-config.xml`, all the placeholders except `${profile}` are resolved correctly. Is there any way to resolve that placeholder from the URL?

Example of output:

```xml
<name>${profile}-another-conf</name>
<connection>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/localdb</url>
    <username>appuser</username>
    <password>localpassword</password>
</connection>
<someconf>100</someconf>
```

Versions:

1. Spring Boot - 3.0.5
2. Spring Cloud - 2022.0.1
3. Java - 17

I tried the following placeholders as well, but nothing seems to work.

1. `${profiles}`
2. `${spring.profiles}`
3. `${spring.profiles.active}`
4. `${profile}`

The expected result was

```xml
<name>local-another-conf</name>
<connection>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/localdb</url>
    <username>appuser</username>
    <password>localpassword</password>
</connection>
<someconf>100</someconf>
```